# How can I stop a thread in wxpython?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, wxwidgets

**[PROBLEM]**
I want to stop thread that calls a function.

**[CODE]**

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
import threading
shutdown_event = threading.Event()
def testFunction(event):
    while not shutdown_event.is_set():
        import time
        for i in range(2):
            print ('win','r')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            print ('abc')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            print ('enter')
            time.sleep (0.5)
            print 'sleep'
            time.sleep (3)


def startThread(event):
    import threading
    th = threading.Thread(target=testFunction, args=(event,))
    th.start()


def stopThread(event):
    shutdown_event.set()



addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Start", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(addButton, (6, 8), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
stopButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Stop", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(stopButton, (8, 9), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, startThread, addButton)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, stopThread, stopButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**[CURRENT]**
Nothing happens if I click on "Stop" button.

**[DESIRED]**
Function "testFunction" should stop if I click on "Stop" button.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is stopping, the thing is that it's not being interrupted, it is running until both iterations of your script have finished, then the `while condition` is checked, and THEN it stops.

```
import wx
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
top = wx.Frame(None)
sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
import threading
shutdown_event = threading.Event()
def testFunction(event):
    while not shutdown_event.is_set():
        import time
        for i in range(2):
            print u"Iteración {}".format(i)
            if shutdown_event.is_set():
                break;
            print ('win','r')
            time.sleep (0.1)
            if shutdown_event.is_set():
                break;
            print ('abc')
            time.sleep (0.1)
            if shutdown_event.is_set():
                break;
            print ('enter')
            time.sleep (0.1)
            if shutdown_event.is_set():
                break;
            print 'sleep'
            time.sleep (0.5)
        print u"Fin de ejecución\n\n"
    print u"Se detuvo la ejecución.\n\n"


def startThread(event):
    import threading
    th = threading.Thread(target=testFunction, args=(event,))
    th.start()


def stopThread(event):
    shutdown_event.set()


addButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Start", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(addButton, (6, 8), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
stopButton = wx.Button( top, -1, "Stop", style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT )
sizer.Add(stopButton, (8, 9), (2, 14), wx.EXPAND)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, startThread, addButton)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, stopThread, stopButton)
top.Sizer = sizer
top.Sizer.Fit(top)
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I understand your point. my goal is to stop the function right when i click on stop btn. in other words, if the function has a total of 5 steps and I click "Stop" when the function is at step 3, then step 4 should not be executed anymore.

Comment: Then you'll have to add a `'break` or `continue` after before each step.

Comment: [plus1] because I was too lazy to look up how best to break out of a ``while`` loop :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a finer granularity in your thread, you have to implement that. Use something like this, splitting up the different steps in a generator statement with the `yield` statement:

```
def testFunction(event):
    def inner_gen():
        print ('win','r')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        yield
        print ('abc')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        yield
        print ('enter')
        time.sleep (0.5)
        yield
        print 'sleep'
        time.sleep (3)
        yield

    while True:
        for _ in range(2):
            for _ in inner_gen():
                if shutdown_event.is_set():
                    shutdown_event.clear()
                    return
```